# How can i get menu description in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla3.2

I want to get  Joomla menu description in mod_menu/default.php .
How can i get it to modify?

[image: Joomla menu description]

Comment: By default there is not such option provided.
You need to overwrite the module and add an sql query to get the desc value of the menu. What is the purpose of this ?

Comment: Also, the SE Joomla beta site has been launched. Why not posting in there ? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my purpose is find a way that administrator can add a text as description  before load menu by overwrite module content.but this purpose need a parameter that show in admin panel.i don`t know how it can possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the database from your module to get the Menu Description of your desired menu:

The code will look like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery( true );
$query->select( 'description' )
    ->from( '#__menu_types' )
    ->where( 'id = '{your menu item id, e.g. 1}' );

$db->setQuery( $query );
$description = $db->loadResult();
```